# codeigniter multilingual form_validation_lang.php

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

I am trying to make a multilingual site with Codeigniter, and for the content this works fine by loading the `_lang.php` file from the right language folder dynamically from the controller. It's just that I don't get how to do this with the  `form_validation_lang.php file`.

Is there a way to set what folder it should take the `_lang.php` files from the controller?

Here is what I used, leaving most set_rules() lines out.

```
  $this->lang->load('MY_register_lang', $this->_language);
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->lang->load('form_validation', $this->_language);

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'lang:un', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]|alpha_dash|is_unique[user.username]');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass2', 'lang:pass2', 'trim|required|matches[pass1]');
  $this->form_validation->set_message('matches', $this->lang->line('no_match'));
```

It does load the right MY_register_lang.php, but not the form_validation_lang.php (yes, tried adding the _lang). it does use the right language from the set_message() method, but that comes from the file that does get loaded.

Comment: Does it? language file name should be called without `_lang`.Does your language file name `MY_register_lang_lang.php`?

Comment: Yes,  it loads like that. It's called MY_register_lang.php.

Comment: `$this->lang->load('form_validation', $this->_language);` loads your current language file. If you want to load it with fixed language you should write it statically. like `$this->lang->load('form_validation', 'english');` it will always load English file even your language is different.

Comment: Somehow it loads the standard language file after $this->lang->load('form_validation', $this->_language); If if change both filenames(both form_validation_lang.php), it gives and error about the right (dutch) file. If i correct that specific form_validation_lang.php, it gives an error saying it cant find the english file. so it seems to load them both, but I have no clue where the default language gets loaded

Comment: It seems you have two language file for English.one is inside `\application\language\english` and another one is inside `system\language\english` backup and delete the system one. And the proper way to load a language file is `$this->lang->load('form_validation', 'english');` but file name should be `form_validation_lang.php`. This is incorrect way `$this->lang->load('form_validation_lang', 'english');`  I wonder how this works for your `$this->lang->load('MY_register_lang', $this->_language);`

Comment: somehow that _lang does not make a difference. There's no second english file.

Comment: Try to load the language file after `$this->form_validation->run()` or end of the function after validation complete.

Comment: Thanx again for the help. That did not do the trick, but I found out what does. $this->config->set_item('language', $this->_language); did the trick.

Comment: In that case I understood your question wrong. I was trying give you reverse answer.I thought you always want to load `english` language for form_validation what ever your site language is

Answer (score 0):

Please look at CI documentation [Loading A Language File](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html#loading-a-language-file)

It says **In order to fetch a line from a particular file you must load the file first. Loading a language file is done with the following code.**

```
$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');
```

So your case it should be

```
$this->lang->load('form_validation', 'YOUR_SPECIFIC_LANGUAGE');
```

But load the file before you using form validation rules and after loading the library(`$this->load->library('form_validation');`)

Comment: Sadly that does not work. I did it in that precise order, and it does not change the language, where it does do that for the content...

Comment: You should update your question with related codes what you did and what you expect it to be and what you getting

Comment: ok, maybe that helps clearing it up a bit. thanx for the effort so far :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set a custom error message for a particular field on some particular rule, use the set_rules() method with lang:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('field_name', 'Field Label', 'rule1|rule2|rule3',
        array('rule2' => lang('your_lang_keyword'))
);
```

This will solve your all fields problem independently. :)